# Erro dependencias JasperReport

Tags: java

Uso o Netbeans. No meu Maven tenho esta dependência para o JasperReport:

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
         <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Mas acontece que construo o .jar com as bibliotecas inclusas, ai quando executo o sistema dá esta mensagem de erro:

`Error: a JNI error has occurred please check your installation and try again`

Só acontece quando incluo as dependências do JasperReport e só no .jar. Direto no Netbeans não acontece o erro....

----------------------- EDIT -----------------------

Meu pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.softcom</groupId>
    <artifactId>AtendimentoCliente</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jaybird -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JasperReport -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
             <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
             <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>AtendimentoCliente</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>forms.FormConsultaSac</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>  

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Eu coloco este plugin, pois se eu deixar sem, o Netbeans não gera o .jar com as dependências, mesmo clicando com botão direito no projeto e mandando construir com dependências.

Apaguei todos os .jar do repositório do Maven, aí ele baixou tudo de novo. As dependências que foram baixadas para meu projeto são essas:

[image: Imagem das dependências]

Mesmo apagando as dependências e baixando de novo o erro continuou. E o erro acontece só no .jar, direto no Netbeans funciona...

Será que pode ser este plugin? Tentei apagá-lo, mas como disse antes, se eu apagar, o Netbeans gera o .jar sem as dependências

Comment: Parece que o .jar está corrompido, já tentou apagar a lib na pasta do maven e baixar novamente?

Comment: Já tentei sim, continua com o erro...

Comment: Tem certeza de que não tem uma exceção mais detalhada? Tente aumentar o nível de log para `DEBUG`.

Comment: Mais uma coisa: alguns plugins permitem você modificar classes e pacotes ao gerar o ubber jar. Isso também pode causar esse tipo de problema. Outro fator pode ser que na hora de montar o JAR algumas classes são sobrescritas por versões diferentes, enquanto que no seu Netbeans por acaso a versão certa está sendo carregada. Procure por conflito de versões na árvore de dependências. O jasper costuma trazer muitas dependências e talvez a solução seja excluir algumas delas.